# Extended expiration on JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt

When we are talking about JWT authentication, how big of a security risk would it be to eliminate the concept of a refresh token and just have a single JWT have an expiration time of, let's say 30 days.

The refresh token could still be accessed by a cookie / local storage (even though many people also thinks this is a security risk),

So theoretically, would it not be the same thing if an attacker could also just get a new token with the refresh token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean sessions stored in JWT tokens then you are increasing the risk of session hijacking. The concept behind expiring sessions is so if an attacker did gain access to the session token it will be limited or already expired.

The refresh token is used if the user logged in is still active and you would like to refresh the session token before it will get expired. The refresh token is only used when communicating with an authentication endpoint while the session token is used throughout the application. The sensitivity of the refresh token is higher which is why it is limited to the auth resource which will sometimes be a separate server (You can read more about it [here](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/oauth/vSmJ0zjQzZFjeFbRz_qpvjfpAeU/)).

Some applications leave the session token active for a very long time, this is depended on the sensitivity of the resource being accessed. You should make your own calculation to how long you would like to provide the session token but be aware that the longer a session will take to expire, the higher chance a session hijacking can occur.